# Is there a way that you can print this code instead of having an onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a puzzle website where you select a puzzle, I was wondering if there was a way of, instead of it being in pop up boxes it would be printed to the website. I don't mind what code we are using as I am fluent in most,

This is the code I have so far:

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{

        function ask() {
    var a = (Math.round(Math.random()*1000000))
    alert (a)
    return prompt("What was the number?") == eval( a );
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;

alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correct");

}

</script>

<button onClick="myFunction()">Remember the number</button>


</body>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction2(){

        function ask() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    return prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;

alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correct");
}
</script>

<button onClick="myFunction2()">Quick math</button>

</body>

</html>
</html>
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to make it show up as text and have a text box on the page to type into that would still work. And the design is able to be changed, so I can make a larger text box, or a larger font so it's not just an un-editable onclick.

All help greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at Jquery UI Dialogs https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Have a look at jquery `.append()` and `.remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did what I thought that you wanted to the "Remember the number" button click.
Sorry, had no time to do the other one.

HTML:

```
<body>


<button id="rmbrBtn">Remember the number</button>


</body>

<body>


<button id="quivkBtn">Quick math</button>
    <div id="question_area">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
</html>
```

JS & jQuery code:

```
$("#rmbrBtn").click(function()
{
    // Answers collection
    var questions = [];

    // Check the correctness of the answer
    function checkAnswer (){
            total = questions.length,
            correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;
        if(total < 5)
        {
            ask();
        }else{
            var answer = '<div>You got '+correct+'/'+total+' correct <input type="button" value="Ok" id="ansOk"/></div>';
            $("#question_area").append(answer);
            $("#ansOk").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().empty();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        }
    }

    // Get the question
    function ask() {
        var a = (Math.round(Math.random()*1000000));
        // View the generated number
        var viewNumber = '<div>'+a+'<input type="button" id="ok" value="OK"/>'+'</div>';

        // Prompt user with a text box
        var promptVal = '<div>Enter your value: <input type="text" id="ans" /> <input   type="button" id="prmtOk" value="Ok"/></div>';

        // Append
        $("#question_area").append(viewNumber);

        $("#ok").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().empty();
            $(this).parent().remove();

            $("#question_area").append(promptVal);  

            $("#prmtOk").click(function(){
               var prmt = $("#ans").val();
               var addVal = prmt == a;
                questions.push(addVal);
                checkAnswer();
                $(this).parent().empty();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
    }

    // Run the function.
    checkAnswer();
});
```

Online solution:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/holo/gLN87/)

Try to do the other one same as this.

Sorry had no time to comment also.

I think you can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div at the top of your page and use jqueries .html() and you will be done

like

```
$('.header').html('You are correct.');
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/8nWKD/3/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done without JQuery and just JavaScript.
http://jsfiddle.net/8nWKD/4/

```
<div id="header" class="header">This is the header</div>
<div class="button" onClick="test_click()"> Click me!</div>
```

and the JavaScript

```
function test_click()
{
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "CORRECT!";   
}
```